# Looking for design pattern: Method overriding without subclassing

Tags: design-patterns, subclassing, overriding

Consider the following scenario: I have a class `A` composed of various parts `Part 1`, `Part 2`, etc., and I want to extend the functionality of `A` by subclassing.

The issue: if I tried to override the behaviour of the individual "Parts" (is there a better term?) the same way, I would have to create one subclass for each Part that changes, which gets messy and confusing quickly.

> In a nutshell: I want to override class methods without resorting to
>   subclassing.

I thought of a solution, but I'm unsure if it is a good idea:

Suppose I want to override `Part::Method`. Instead of using the inheritance mechanism provided by my language, I could "fake" an overriding capability by:

- passing the `Part` class a function `MethodOverride` (e.g. as an anonymous function), and
- having `Part::Method` call `MethodOverride`

I can see two downsides to that approach:

- it ignores the (perfectly capable but impractical) inheritance feature of the language, which may have unforeseen side-effects
- access non-public members of `Part` becomes a hassle

> My question(s): Is there an established design pattern that solves the
>   described issue in a similar (or better) way? Are there any downsides
>   I missed?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the [strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy), but I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by a `Part`. Possibly, the design would be improved by separating each Part into its own class.

Comment: You might have better answers if you specify what are A, Part 1, Part 2... context makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to avoid subclassing but still require the ability to provide a set of classes related algorithms, you're usually looking at the visitor pattern.

Each class will compose a visitor object, and call one of it's functions. This eliminates the need to subclass multiple objects just to get a method.

[Visitor Pattern Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm)

Like mentioned above your example of passing in a method override is very similar to the strategy pattern, but according to your post...

> I would have to create one subclass for each Part that changes

I'm assuming the point is to avoid creating multiple classes, only to provide limited functionality. Both your method override example and the strategy pattern require a class for each different override/strategy (algorithm).

[Strategy Pattern Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm)

The visitor only adds one class, and keeps all the logic in the visitor class. No need to subclass multiple times, just add a new algorithm into the visitors concrete implementation.

Comment: I don't think that example is a Visitor. Compare it with the linked example: there are significant differences.

Comment: @jaco0646 I'm trying to give a small example how the algorithms are contained in one class and skipped the interfaces for brevity. The link is a full example but the example is my best attempt to show concept of a class that contains what would be implemented in one place to avoid subclassing with minimal amount of code.

Comment: @jaco0646 I changed my mind. An incorrect example to demonstrate a concept is just confusing. I also don't think it's helpful to create a whole long  example guessing what his classes do....so I just removed it. Ideally the link is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and please excuse the delay.  The Visitor pattern, after some investigation, turned out to be just what I needed. Thanks!